# Qt5 ui, multiple windows: how can I access the Ui objects in Window 2 from Window 1

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I know this is very clunky and I'm probably doing a lot of wrong things but so far everything I saw on the net gives back the same errors: invalid use of non-static data member ui.

So in the MainWindow, I have a comboBox named **hometeam**, and I want to display the currentText on a Qlabel named **label** which is on another Form Class called *Dialog*

I figured they're both private members so I added *friend class MainWindow* and *friend class dialog* in the respective headers (I know this is pretty wrong but it's the last thing I tried), I included the "ui_mainwindow" and "ui_dialog" in the .cpp files, and here's the bit of code I'm trying:

```
   ui->label->setText(MainWindow::ui->hometeam->currentTex());
```

Keep in mind that I don't want a QDialog, the second window will do a lot more than a display, I just want to access the objects from a different window. Slots and signals give the same error.

Thanks !

Comment: do you have a class where you can connect them both the MainWindow and the Dialog???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way to do that, is to add a function to your `MainWindow` class:

```
QString hometeamText() const
{
    return ui->hometeam->currentTex();
}
```

This way you can access the information you need without violating encapsulation rules, but you need an **instance** of `MainWindow` to do it, and sure must keep a pointer to it in your `Dialog` class:

```
class Dialog
{
private:
    MainWindow * mainwindow;
public:
    void setMainWindow(MainWindow * w) { mainWindow = w; }
```

then somewhere (e.g. in `main`) you can do something like:

```
MainWindow mainwindow;
Dialog dialog;
dialog.setMainWindow(&mainWindow);
```

and from inside your `Dialog` class, wherever you need it:

```
ui->label->setText(window->hometeamText());
```

Comment: Yep this is it, now I just feel dumb because we've doing something similar to this in class for the last month lol. Anyway, cheers man !